# YouTube Live Webhook Callback Content Empty

Tags: node.js, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

This is my callback endpoint for the pubsubhub' for YT Live, and it is getting requests from YouTube when I go live, but it's output is empty.

```
server.post('/yt_webhook', async function(req,res){
    console.log('in post');
    console.log(req.read());
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log(req.query);
    res.status(200);
    res.send();
})
```

the output for this is

```
in post
null
{}
{}
```

when the documentation states that it should be an XML formatted thing of youtube videos. Searching through the full request object I see nothing pointing to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using express-xml-bodyparser as middleware does the trick. Now I have:

```
var xmlbodyparser = require('express-xml-bodyparser');
server.use(xmlbodyparser())
server.post('/yt_webhook', async function(req,res){
    console.log(req.body);
    res.status(200);
    res.send();
})
```